# p-values of standardized vs non-standardized regression model coefficients - are they the same?

Tags: p-value, regression-coefficients, standardization, lm

I made the following simple regression model and used stargazer to output a table that plots the standardized vs non-standardized regression model coefficients.

```
mod = lm(mtcars$mpg~mtcars$cyl+mtcars$disp)
mod_std = lm.beta(mod)

stargazer(mod, mod_std, 
          coef = list(mod$coefficients, 
                  mod_std$standardized.coefficients),
          type='text')
```

```
==========================================================
                                  Dependent variable:     
                              ----------------------------
                                          mpg             
                                   (1)            (2)     
----------------------------------------------------------
cyl                              -1.587**       -0.470    
                                 (0.712)        (0.712)   
                                                          
disp                             -0.021**      -0.423***  
                                 (0.010)        (0.010)   
                                                          
Constant                        34.661***        0.000    
                                 (2.547)        (2.547)   
                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------
Observations                        32            32      
R2                                0.760          0.760    
Adjusted R2                       0.743          0.743    
Residual Std. Error (df = 29)     3.055          3.055    
F Statistic (df = 2; 29)        45.808***      45.808***  
==========================================================
Note:                          *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

What I see here is that of course, the coefficients are different between the non-standardized and standardized model. Then, the standard errors of the coefficients are the same.

What I do not understand is the p-values associated with these estimates. They seem to change between the standardized and non-standardized models. Does this mean that in the case of which we compute the standardized coefficients, we automatically get new p-values that are associated with these new estimates?

This is confusing because if I do a summary on my standardized model:

```
> summary(mod_std)

Call:
lm(formula = mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl + mtcars$disp)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.4213 -2.1722 -0.6362  1.1899  7.0516 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Standardized Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 34.66099      0.00000    2.54700  13.609 4.02e-14 ***
mtcars$cyl  -1.58728     -0.47035    0.71184  -2.230   0.0337 *  
mtcars$disp -0.02058     -0.42328    0.01026  -2.007   0.0542 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.055 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7596,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.743 
F-statistic: 45.81 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 1.058e-09
```

There is no distinction between p-values of the standardized vs non-standardized regression coefficients. So I thought that the p-values would be the same. Is this wrong?

Reference for lm.beta: Stefan Behrendt (2014). lm.beta: Add Standardized Regression Coefficients to lm-Objects. R package version 1.5-1. https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=lm.beta

Comment: Please edit the question to add a citation to the source of the`lm.beta()` function, as that's not in the standard R distribution. If there is any scaling of the coefficients then their standard errors should also be scaled correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my post to cite the package. Then I am a bit confused: maybe the stargazer package does not scale the standard errors automatically? So this may be a problem with it? So in a sense, if I understand correctly: if we scale coefficients, we automatically have different standard errors and different p-values?

Comment: I see no change in p-values whatsoever.  Could you indicate what you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Looking at the first screenshot of the output of stargazer: the coefficient of non-standardized cyl is "-1.587** std. error = 0.712 while for the standardized version it is -0.470 (not significant) with the same std. error = 0.712. This is the confusing part for me - it seems that the standard error is the same for standardized and non-standardized, while the p-values (and therefore the significance of the estimates between standardized and non-standardized) are different. Or maybe I am misunderstanding something?